# How to avoid creating schemas for the table which exists already in the DB while using FastApi Pydantic schemas

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

We are in situation to create the separate API in Python FastApi for one functionality. Other functionality in Laravel. The application which exists already. It created set of tables and using them. Now, we are required to create Pydantic schemas for new API. That schema has a relationship with existing tables. We don't want to create separate schemas for existing tables.

We are forced to create schemas for existing tables as well in the new API. We don't want to create the separate schemas and models for existing tables.

Kindly suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I understand correctly this application is written in PHP?

Comment: Yes, the actual application is written on PHP. This is not regarding to application. We are making use of the application. But we dont want touch anything in laravel. We are building separate feature which is on Python fast api.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about automatic documentation you don't need to use pydantic at all - you can just return dict and use **swagger**. If you do, I have no good news.

As far as I know it's not easily achievable. Even if you have tables definitions implemented in sqlalchemy there is not easy way of creating schema from them ([there is a tool](https://github.com/tiangolo/pydantic-sqlalchemy) but it's still experimental).

There are ORM's that can do that (like [tortoise](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20tortoise)) but you still need to implement schema somewhere. Dynamic creation of python class based on database schema would be very hard, very long, very bugable and would break static checkers so I am pretty sure they never exist.